# Troubleshooting MAMP Continually Not Responding

Tags: macos, configuration, mamp, mamp-pro

I have a MAMP setup which hosts a number of local servers. It seems capable of running them just fine but it seems almost daily the app itself is marked as not responding by the OS (macOS 10.15.2) and as such refuses to close the app at the end of the day. This becomes quite irritating as it happens constantly. I imagine I've changed something, perhaps related to RAM so it thinks it can use more than it can. Searching for *"MAMP Not Responding"* on google doesn't exactly show what I'm looking for though.

Any help diagnosing **MAMP itself** rather than the servers freezing up?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same behavior on macOS 10.15.4 with MAMP Pro 5.7. The server processes are still up and running but the app itself shows the spinning wheel of death. Besides the need to force quit MAMP Pro each time at the end of the day (+ restart to stop the servers) it seems like the program is eating up quite a lot of resources when it freezes.

Comment: Happens to me too, no solution so far, MAMP Pro, so pay to lose here.

Comment: @Liquinaut At the end of the day?  It's more like "at the end of the hour" for me lately.  :(

Comment: I switched to Linux + Lando and haven't looked back ever since.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to help me out.

1. Quit MAMP if open
2. Navigate to /MAMP/tmp/mysql
3. Rename mysql.sock.lock
4. Restart MAMP

I got this from [MrSandman98765](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13239539/mrsandman98765) answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063332/2314252

Comment: There's no mysql.sock.lock file in MAMP/tmp/mysql. I'm on macOS Big Sur, and the MAMP folder is in /Applications. I've already restarted or updated MAMP Pro to the current latest, 6.6.2. I don't know what else to do except maybe upgrade macOS to Monterey, but I don't see why that's necessary when MAMP was working fine Friday with nothing changed over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve partially fixed it tweaking MySQL settings File > Edit templates > MySQL (my.cfn) > 5.7.26

In my case, having 64 GB of Ram, I’ve heavily increased everything related to Ram and buffer size.

I saw “partially” because sometimes, working on large Magento sites I get again the issue. I think it could be better investigated with MySQL tuning tools.

Comment: I don't use MySQL in MAMP, and it's disabled in settings. No matter what I'm doing, MAMP just suddenly won't start today.

Answer (score 0):

As may others will visit, for me **MAMP PRO (v. 6.8)** got stuck, which was very annoying. Above mentioned did unfortunately not solve the frozen/stuck state of MAMP PRO on my machine.
What helped me:

- Simple quit MAMP PRO App and
- **kill de.appsolute.mampprohelper** via Activity Monitor

Seems like de.appsolute.mampprohelper is also starting when staring MAMP Pro App.
After that, it seems more stable.
Hope that helps.